# Using Cases and when to make input a list or not

Tags: pattern-matching

I am back learning pattern matching in Mathematica, which I am not good at.

An input is a mathematica expression, and I need to simply get a list of all the sub-expressions inside this expression of the pattern `(any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.])` anywhere in the expression.

`c` above is the literal symbol. All others are patterns.

For example, the above pattern will match $e^{c +x}$ or $4 e^{5 c+ x}$ and so on. So I tried it and it works, except when the input expression contains a single `Exp[...]`

**case 1, works**

```
ClearAll[x,y,c]
expr=x y +4 Exp[c + y]+5 Sin[x]+Exp[c + x]
Cases[expr,(any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**case 2, works**

```
expr=x y +4 Exp[c + y]+5 Sin[x]
Cases[expr,(any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**case 3, do not work**

```
expr=4 Exp[c + y]
Cases[expr,(any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

the `4` was dropped out in the above. And when there is a single `Exp` it does not work at all

**case 4, do not work**

```
expr=Exp[c + y]
Cases[expr,(any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I can handle these last two special cases by forcing the input to be a list

```
expr=Exp[c + y]
Cases[{expr},(any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But if I do the above, then the first two cases now fail. So I changed the test to be as follows

```
If[Head[expr] === Plus,
 Cases[expr, (any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.])]
 ,
 Cases[{expr}, (any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.])]
 ]
```

And now the above works for all of 4 cases. (But I am not sure if it will fail for some cases I have not thought about as I only check for `Plus` head)

**My question is**, is the above a correct way to do all of this, or is there a better and canonical way to handle this in Mathematica?

**Update:**
Thanks to all the answers. But I also need it to work for division. As in this new case

**case 5**

```
 expr = Exp[c + x]/(3 + Exp[3*c + x]);
```

So in the above, it should find `Exp[c + x]` and `Exp[3*c + x]` separately.  The whole idea, is that I want to rewrite any subexpression `Exp[any1_*c + any2_]` as `c*Exp[any2]`

I did say in the original question above `anywhere in the expression` but I did not put the above case in there and I was just now testing the answers given and noticed this problem.

Comment: Use the level specs to include level 0 : `Cases[expr, (any0_.  Exp[any1_. c + any2_.]), {0, Infinity}]`?

Comment: @kglr But your method will now return 2 hits for this: `4 Exp[c + y]`, it returned `{E^(c+y),4 E^(c+y)}` and I only wanted `4 E^(c+y)` ? screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L0YoY.png)

Comment: `Cases[expr, (any0_.  Exp[any1_. c + any2_.]), {0}]` gives a single hit.

Comment: @kglr Sure, now it gives single hit on this case, but for case 1 it now returns empty list !  `expr = x y + 4 Exp[c + y] + 5 Sin[x];
Cases[expr, (any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.]), {0}]` gives empty list.  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yCbCU.png)  This is not as easy as it looks :) I need a method that works for all cases.

Comment: Nasser, it does give an empty list as it should. For _"a method that works for all cases"_,  you need to decide and specify the levels you you are looking for a match:  `4 Exp[c + y]` will have two matches for levelspec `{0,1}`and one for levelspec `0`. With your `If[...]` approach you are just adding one  more level to input expr (hence default levelspec 1 kicks in). In general the _pattern_ in the second argument, in addition to being inside an expression with any `Head`, can be at arbitrary depth (consider `y + foo[bar[4 Exp[c=y]]` for example).

Comment: @kglr But I do not know what the expression will look like. That is why I asked. I need a way to find all occurrences of `(any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.])` anywhere in the expression. This will be inside a black box function that user calls with an expression. You say I need to specify the level. But how? I do not know what the expression will be like. Are you saying in Mathematica it is not possible to write such a general pattern matching?

Comment: Nasser, _"to find *all* occurrences of "_ a _pattern_,  *anywhere* in an _expr_, using `Cases`, afaik you need `{0, Infinity}` as the third argument of `Cases`.  But this returns 2 hits for `4 Exp[c + y]` and you only want `4 E^(c+y)` although  `E^(c+y)` is a perfectly legitimate occurrence of your _pattern_ inside  `4 Exp[c + y]`. If you have a criterion in mind (that is totally different from what levelspecs can express) that determines why only `4 Exp[c + y]`  and not `Exp[c + y]`  matches `(any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.])`  in `expr =4 Exp[c + y]` , ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases), you can use [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll). [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll) will not search inside of a part of the expression that it already replaced, unlike [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases) which searches at every level specified. So:

```
getPatterns[expr_, pat_] := Last @ Reap[
    expr /. a:pat :> Sow[a],
    _,
    Sequence@@#2&
]
```

For your examples:

```
expr1=x y+4 Exp[c+y]+5 Sin[x]+Exp[c+x];
expr2=x y+4 Exp[c+y]+5 Sin[x];
expr3=4 Exp[c+y];
expr4=Exp[c+y];

getPatterns[#, _. Exp[_. c+_.]]& /@ {expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4}
```

> {{E^(c + x), 4 E^(c + y)}, {4 E^(c + y)}, {4 E^(c + y)}, {E^(c + y)}}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just found the above does not work for division? Here is an example: `expr = Exp[c + x]/(3 + Exp[3*c + x])
getPatterns[expr, (_. Exp[_. c + _.])]` and this does not find `Exp[c + x]` and `Exp[3*c + x]`, but it returns the whole expression back. Is it hard to make your function find these patterns also in there is a division? I did not put this example in my question, but I said `anywhere in the expression.` :) and I was now just testing this answer. I should add this case now. Thanks.

Comment: The whole expression does match the pattern, it is `1/(3 + Exp[3 c+x])` times `Exp[c+x]`. Perhaps something like `getPatterns[expr, x_. Exp[_. c + _.] /; FreeQ[x, E]]` or `getPatterns[expr, _Integer Exp[_. c + _.]]`?

Comment: Thanks, `getPatterns[expr, x_. Exp[_. c + _.] /; FreeQ[x, E]]` seems to work!  Will test more now. Pattern matching is too hard.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be basically a level specification problem. We can see what's going on by looking a much simpler case.

```
Cases[Exp[c + y], Exp[c + _]]
```

> `{}`

`Cases` will accept expressions with any head, but it normally only looks at the elements at level 1 of the expression. Therefore, in this example, it only sees the argument `c + y`, which does not match the pattern, so it returns an empty list.

There are two work-arrounds.

The obvious one

```
Cases[{Exp[c + y]}, Exp[c + _]]
```

(now Exp[c + y] is at level 1) and the less obvious one

```
Cases[Exp[c + y], Exp[c + _], {0}]
```

(now `Cases` looks at level 0). They both return

> `{E^(c + y)}`

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Maybe something like this

```
ClearAll[caseS]
caseS = Module[{i = 0, res = {}}, While[i < Depth[#] &&
  (res = Cases[{#}, (any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.]), i++])  === {}]; res] &;

expr1 = x y+ 4 Exp[c + y]+ 5 Sin[x] + Exp[c + x];
expr2 = x y+ 4 Exp[c + y]+ 5 Sin[x];
expr3 = 4 Exp[c + y];
expr4 = Exp[c + y];

caseS /@ {expr1, expr2, expr3, expr4}
```

> {{E^(c + x), 4 E^(c + y)}, {4 E^(c + y)}, {4 E^(c + y)}, {E^(c + y)}}

```
caseS /@ {foo[expr1], {expr2}, {{{bar @@ {{expr3}}}}}, {{{expr4}}}}
```

> {{E^(c + x), 4 E^(c + y)}, {4 E^(c + y)}, {4 E^(c + y)}, {E^(c + y)}}

**Original answer:**

```
expr = 4 Exp[c + y]
Cases[expr, (any0_.  Exp[any1_. c + any2_.]), {0, Infinity}]
```

> {E^(c + y), 4 E^(c + y)}

Or get the matches in level 0 only:

```
Cases[expr, (any0_.  Exp[any1_. c + any2_.]), {0}]
```

> {4 E^(c + y)}

```
expr = Exp[c + y]
Cases[expr, (any0_. Exp[any1_. c + any2_.]), {0, Infinity}]]
```

> {E^(c + y)}

From [Cases >> Details and options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html):

> - *The default value for levelspec in Cases is {1}.*

And `4 Exp[c + y]` has two elements `Level` 1

```
Level[4 Exp[c + y], 1]
```

> {4, E^(c + y)}

Only the second matches the pattern and is returned by `Cases` with default levelspec.

Similarly,

```
Level[Exp[c + y], 1]
```

> {E, c + y}

none of which matches the pattern specified.

You need to include level 0 to force pattern matching to include the whole expression.

Comment: Thanks, but please see comment above. This returns 2 hits for `4 Exp[c + y]` when I only expect one  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L0YoY.png)

Comment: Using `{0}` does not work on case 1  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DFL6e.png) and using  `{0, Infinity}` gives two hits for `4 Exp[c + y]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K1ldN.png) I am looking for one method that will work for all cases. But thanks for the input.

Comment: +1 thanks for information about level. But I am hoping for general method that works for all cases. Will keep trying :)