# DSolve and eigenvalues?

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I have solved a system of $N$ ($N$ is the order of system) ODE with DSolve and found $N$ solutions in the form

```
f[t]={-7.46396*10^-17 + 6.07946*10^-17 E^(-1.80414*10^9 t) -   3.46759*10^-20 
 E^(-5.89008*10^8 t) +   8.06773*10^-20 E^(-2.59966*10^8 t) -   1.44354*10^-19 
 E^(-1.31932*10^8 t) +   3.26139*10^-17 E^(-6.80231*10^7 t) -   1.67078*10^-18 
 E^(-3.13777*10^7 t) +   1.77792*10^-18 E^(-1.91106*10^7 t) +   4.55638*10^-18 
 E^(-1.80114*10^7 t) +   4.3548*10^-19 E^(-1.61636*10^7 t) +   1.90158*10^-18 
 E^(-1.33903*10^7 t) -   7.98234*10^-19 E^(-9.09799*10^6 t) -   1.21329*10^-18 
 E^(-7.28863*10^6 t) +   1.05423*10^-18 E^(-5.44168*10^6 t) - 2.47138*10^-17 
 E^(-279052. t)}
```

(this is only the first one) and also other $N-1$ solutions. This solution evidently has the following representation $f(t)=\sum_{i}c_{i}e^{\lambda_{i}t}$, where $\lambda_{i}$ are the eigenvalues and $c_{i}$ are the coefficients of eigenvector. The question is: how to obtain vector $\bf c$ and table of $\lambda_{i}$ separatly ? I have only the solution given above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-line solution:

```
{c, eig} = (Level[f[t], 1] /. {a__*Exp[b__*t] :> {a, b}, 
     x_ /; NumericQ[x] -> {x, 0}})\[Transpose]
```

test:

```
f[t] = -7.46396*10^-17 + 6.07946*10^-17 E^(-1.80414*10^9 t) - 
  3.46759*10^-20 E^(-5.89008*10^8 t) + 
  8.06773*10^-20 E^(-2.59966*10^8 t) - 
  1.44354*10^-19 E^(-1.31932*10^8 t) + 
  3.26139*10^-17 E^(-6.80231*10^7 t) - 
  1.67078*10^-18 E^(-3.13777*10^7 t) + 
  1.77792*10^-18 E^(-1.91106*10^7 t) + 
  4.55638*10^-18 E^(-1.80114*10^7 t) + 
  4.3548*10^-19 E^(-1.61636*10^7 t) + 
  1.90158*10^-18 E^(-1.33903*10^7 t) - 
  7.98234*10^-19 E^(-9.09799*10^6 t) - 
  1.21329*10^-18 E^(-7.28863*10^6 t) + 
  1.05423*10^-18 E^(-5.44168*10^6 t) - 2.47138*10^-17 E^(-279052. t)


Grid[{c, eig}\[Transpose], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get the eigenvalues, I use Carl Woll's `getPatterns`

```
pat=getPatterns[f[t], Exp[n__ t]]
eig=Cases[pat,Exp[n_ t]:>n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the `c's`

```
 pat=getPatterns[f[t], m__ Exp[n__ t]]
 c=Cases[pat,m__ Exp[n_ t]:>m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Grid[Transpose[{c,eig}],Frame->All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This function thanks to  Carl Woll, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151850/using-cases-and-when-to-make-input-a-list-or-not)

```
getPatterns[expr_, pat_] := 
  Last@Reap[expr /. a : pat :> Sow[a], _, Sequence @@ #2 &];
```

Comment: note that the 1st term is a constant and may be seen as `c * exp[0 t]` which is not matched by this pattern