# Transpose::nmtx error when using Greek Formal symbol in NDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, symbols

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier, persisting through 12.2.**

---

Consider the following call to `NDSolveValue` for a system of ODEs with 2 dependent variables, where we may choose the first dependent variable, `symbol`, to be any symbol except `y` or `t`:

```
solver[symbol : Except[y | t, _Symbol]] :=
  NDSolveValue[
    {symbol'[t] == 1, y'[t] == 1, symbol[0] == 0, y[0] == 0}
    , {symbol, y}
    , {t, 0, 1}
  ];

$Version
(* 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019) *)
```

If we choose ordinary Latin symbols, ordinary Greek symbols, or Formal Latin symbols, this works fine:

```
solver[a]
solver[α]
solver[\[FormalA]]
(* OK *)
```

But if we choose any Formal Greek symbol, we get errors:

```
solver[\[FormalAlpha]]
```

> `Transpose::nmtx`: The first two levels of `` {\[FormalAlpha], NDSolve`xs$2814} `` cannot be transposed.
> `Part::partw`: Part 2 of `` Transpose[{\[FormalAlpha], NDSolve`xs$2814}] `` does not exist.
> etc.

What is it about Greek Formal symbols which causes things to break?

Interestingly, multi-character symbols *containing* Formal Greek are OK:

```
solver[a\[FormalAlpha]]
solver[\[FormalAlpha]\[FormalAlpha]]
(* OK *)
```

Also note that the error does not occur if there is only 1 dependent variable in `NDSolveValue`.

Comment: Interesting. _v12.2_ spits out `ndode` warning. Looks like a bug. Have you reported it to WRI?

Comment: @xzczd Reporting now, wanted to see if others could reproduce

Comment: Reported, assigned ID \[CASE:4742880\]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*v12.2* spits out `ndode` warning. This seems to be a bug *related* to the undocumented function `` Internal`ProcessEquations`FindDependentVariables `` (I know it from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221856/1871) BTW):

```
Table[
 Internal`ProcessEquations`FindDependentVariables[{symbol'[t] == 1, y'[t] == 1, 
   symbol[0] == 0, y[0] == 0}, t], {symbol, {\[FormalAlpha], a\[FormalAlpha]}}]
(* {{y}, {a\[FormalAlpha], y}} *)
```

As we can see, it fails to find the single `\[FormalAlpha]`. But this function doesn't show up in `Trace[NDSolveValue[………], TraceInternal->True]`, and I've no idea why `NDSolve` succeeds in handling the 1 dependent variable case.

Luckily, the problem is easy to circumvent. Just set the `DependentVariables` option:

```
With[{symbol = \[FormalAlpha]}, 
 NDSolveValue[{symbol'[t] == 1, y'[t] == 1, symbol[0] == 0, y[0] == 0}, {symbol, y}, 
   {t, 0, 1}, DependentVariables -> {symbol, y}]]
```